# JPA entitygraph fetchgraph isn't working while loadgraph does

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use JPA dynamic Entity Graphs in Spring MVC. When I use fetchgraph strategy it throws

> "java.lang.illegalArgumentException" with message "Unable to locate
>   Attribute with the given name[ecosystems] on this
>   ManagedType[com.ith.betta.web.models.BaseModel]".

But when I chose loadgraph it works fine. Following are my Entities

> **Order.java**

```
package com.ith.betta.web.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order extends BaseModel {

    private String orderNumber;
    private String type;
    private Integer quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private List<Invoice> invoices;

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(String orderNumber, String type, Integer quantity) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.type = type;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

> **Invoice.java**

```
package com.ith.betta.web.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices")
public class Invoice extends BaseModel {

    @ManyToOne
    private Order order;
}
```

> **User.java**

```
package com.ith.betta.web.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")

public class User extends BaseModel {

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String password;
    private String username;
    private Boolean enabled;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private UserProfile userProfile;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Notification> notifications = new ArrayList<Notification>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Order> orders;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Ecosystem> ecosystems;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String email, String firstName, String lastName, String password, String username) {

        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public UserProfile getUserProfile() {
        return userProfile;
    }

    public void setUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile) {
        this.userProfile = userProfile;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public List<Notification> getNotifications() {
        return notifications;
    }

    public void setNotifications(List<Notification> notifications) {
        this.notifications = notifications;
    }

    @PrePersist
    private void initializeCreatedAndUpdatedAt() {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.createdAt = this.updatedAt = now;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void updateUpdatedAt() {
        this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public List<Ecosystem> getEcosystems() {
        return ecosystems;
    }

    public void setEcosystems(List<Ecosystem> ecosystems) {
        this.ecosystems = ecosystems;
    }
}
```

> **BaseModel.java**

```
package com.ith.betta.web.models;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    protected LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    protected LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

> **and Finally the service class**

```
package com.ith.betta.web.services.impl;

import com.ith.betta.web.models.Order;
import com.ith.betta.web.services.OrderService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.persistence.EntityGraph;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service("orderService")
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Optional<Order> findOrderWithInvoices(Long orderId) {
        EntityGraph graph = em.createEntityGraph(Order.class);
        graph.addSubgraph("invoices");
        Map hints = new HashMap();
        hints.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);
        Order order = em.find(Order.class, orderId, hints);

        return Optional.of(order);

    }
}
```

Now in above setup user relation is creating the problem. When I use loadgraph it works and loads the user as well however no eager load is declared. But when I switch to fetchgraph it try to  find  user -> ecosystem and for some reason it doesn't find it and bubble it up to basemodel.

Relevant Versions being used

- spring-data-releasetrain : Lovelace-RELEASE
- Hibernate : 5.4.0.FINAL
  -

**Edit 1:**
When I change Fetch type of ManyToOne user association to Lazy (By default it is Eager) It starts working, don't know the reason

**Edit 2**
Further digging into it, I removed unique annotation on email column and now it started working on both Lazy and Eager fetch types. Still don't know why